# How do you get the document id after adding document in Cloud Firestore in Dart

Tags: dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

Im using the following code to update a Cloud Firestore collection using Dart/Flutter.

```
  final docRef = Firestore.instance.collection('gameLevels');
  docRef.document().setData(map).then((doc) {
    print('hop');
  }).catchError((error) {
    print(error);
  });
```

I'm trying to get the documentID created when I add the document to the collection but the (doc) parameter comes back as null. I thought it was supposed to be a documentReference?

Since it's null, I obviously can't use doc.documentID.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
DocumentReference docRef = await 
Firestore.instance.collection('gameLevels').add(map);
print(docRef.documentID);
```

Since add() method creates new document and autogenerates id, you don't have to explicitly call document() method

Or if you want to use "then" callback try the following:

```
  final collRef = Firestore.instance.collection('gameLevels');
  DocumentReferance docReference = collRef.document();

  docReferance.setData(map).then((doc) {
    print('hop ${docReferance.documentID}');
  }).catchError((error) {
    print(error);
  });
```

Comment: How do I provide custom ID for my document? I did this but a null pointer exception occurs db.collection('users').document(uid).setData(data);    the document by that id doesn't exist in the db. I want to add it

Comment: The syntax you have is correct. Can you provide exact error log to narrow down the issue? Also check what values present in uid, data variables, to make sure they are not null.

Answer (score 7):

@Doug Stevenson was right and calling doc() method will return you document ID. (I am using cloud_firestore 1.0.3)

To create document you just simply call doc(). For example I want to get message ID before sending it to the firestore.

```
  final document = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('rooms')
      .doc(roomId)
      .collection('messages')
      .doc();
```

I can print and see document's id.

```
print(document.id)
```

To save it instead of calling add() method, we have to use set().

```
  await document.set({
    'id': document.id,
    'user': 'test user',
    'text': "test message",
    'timestamp': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
  });
```

Comment: can't we make it in a single statement like
```dart
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('rooms').doc(roomId).collection('messages')
      .doc().set({
    'id': doc().id,
    'user': 'test user',
    'text': "test message",
    'timestamp': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
  });
```

Answer (score 5):

Using ***value.id*** ,You can fetch ***documentId*** after adding to FireStore .

```
CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('candidates');
  

      Future<void> registerUser() {
     // Call the user's CollectionReference to add a new user
         return users.add({
          'name': enteredTextName, // John Doe
          'email': enteredTextEmail, // Stokes and Sons
          'profile': dropdownValue ,//
          'date': selectedDate.toLocal().toString() ,//// 42
        })
            .then((value) =>(showDialogNew(value.id)))
            .catchError((error) => print("Failed to add user: $error"));
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the Dart APIs are anything like other platforms, the `document()` method should return a document reference that has an id property with the randomly generated id for the document that's about to be added to the collection.

Comment: It works different in Flutter (compared to android/ios). Calling doc() will return you path to the document , which can looks like this DocumentReference(rooms/nJxQna0G7Zay4VHvyZz5/messages/c9cI7YjXOy9SMH2NFzEn)

Comment: My bad, i forgot to print document's ID variable. It should be correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
  //add a passed employee to firebase collection called employees

  static Future<void> addEmployee(Employee employee) async {
    final CollectionReference employees = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('employees');

    var doc = employees.doc();
    employee.employeeID = doc.id;
    await doc.set(employee.toJson());
 }
```