# how to update field in document on cloud firestore using Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I tried to update my firestore database field.

```
  Future<void> approveJob(String categoryId) {
```

**comment line is updated on database. But I hard code uid. Is it possible to get uid without store?**

```
   //return _db.collection('jobs').document('25FgSmfySbhEPe1z539T').updateData({'isApproved':true});


   return _db
        .collection('jobs')
        .where("categoryId", isEqualTo: categoryId)
        .getDocuments()
        .then((v) {
          try{
            v.documents[0].data.update('isApproved', (bool) => true,ifAbsent: ()=>true);

// No Errors. But not updating

         }catch(e){
            print(e);
          }
    });
  }
```

Comment: yes its possible, what you need to do is everytime you save a new document add an id field to it which contains the docId and then you can use this id to do other stuff like update doc

Comment: okay. thanks.. isn't this way update field? `v.documents[0].data.update('isApproved', (bool) => true,ifAbsent: ()=>true);`

Comment: i'm not sure about this but here is how i do my updates `Firestore.instance.collection('collection').document(docId).updateData({`

Answer (score 19):

===December 2020===

There are two methods for updating Firestore documents in Flutter:

1. `set()` - Sets data on the document, overwriting any existing data. If the document does not yet exist, it will be created.
2. `update()` - Updates data on the document. Data will be merged with any existing document data. If no document exists yet, the update will fail.

So, for updating the exact field in the existing document you can use

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collection_name').doc('document_id').update({'field_name': 'Some new data'});
```

Answer (score 7):

- To update a value in the document:

  ```dart
  var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collection');
  collection 
      .doc('doc_id') 
      .update({'key' : 'value'}) // <-- Updated data
      .then((_) => print('Success'))
      .catchError((error) => print('Failed: $error'));
  ```
- To update a nested value in the document.

  ```dart
  var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collection');
  collection 
      .doc('doc_id')
      .update({'key.foo.bar' : 'nested_value'}) // <-- Nested value
      .then((_) => print('Success'))
      .catchError((error) => print('Failed: $error'));
  ```
- To add a new value to the existing document.

  ```dart
  var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collection');
  collection
      .doc('doc_id')
      .set(yourData, SetOptions(merge: true)); // <-- Set merge to true.
  ```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you need to identify and locate the field you want to modify.

```
final code = Code.fromSnapshot(document);

FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collection_Name').doc('doc_Name').collection('collection_Name').doc(code.documentId).update({'redeem': true});
```

In this case `code.documentId` code is the instance that contains the snapshot. By using this it's possible to access the 'identifier' documentId; and then the field `redeem` is changed to true,

Answer (score 2):

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('groups').doc(chatId).collection('groupChat')
        .doc(chatId).update({
      'lastMessage': messageTextController.text.toString(),
      'lastMessageSendBy' : currentUser,
      'lastMessageTime' : Timestamp.now(),
    });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

In order to update a field in a document you just have to follow [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data) documentation.

Regarding how to get the documentID, you could do it as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51056621/11928130)

Also bear in mind that you can [update data with transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions).

Let me know if this was helpful.

Comment: How is your answer related to flutter?