# Connect documents on firebase from android (flutter)

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Restaurant with name and phone.
This restaurant also have a timetable.
What i've done is create a 'Restaurants' collection on firebase and a 'Times' collection. I would like to put in the restaurant document the info about his timetable by adding the timetable Id, but I don't know where to start. Basically I need to link the two documents. Any idea?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054460/how-do-you-get-the-document-id-after-adding-document-in-cloud-firestore-in-dart Solution here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are two ways to doing this first one is whenever you create put document in time collection create document object which can include Restaurant like this

Document of A Restaurant = restaurantId,name,address etc
 Document of A Restaurant Time = timeTableID,restaurantId,etc

or in the second option you can create anthore collection in side restaurant to put you Time document inside that

Answer (score 1):

your data should be like this..

```
var resData = { "name" : "Restaurants1",
                    "phone" : "+1324343434"
                   };    
      var times = {.... your times data};
```

here  col-> Collection() , doc->document()

```
                     ->Col("data").doc().setData(resData);
                   /
  Col("Res").doc(). 
                  \ 
                    ->Col("times").doc().setData(timesData);


 doc() -> generates random id for your document or you can put your id inside 
          document.
```

Happy Coding... :)