# Is there a way to get the current document id in cloud firestore database using python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way to get the current document ID? Because I am trying to update a document field line.

Comment: What do you mean by current document?

Comment: Have you checked this [StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054460/) ?

Comment: The Firestore API does not have a concept of a "current document". Your app may have that concept of course, but we can't see that unless you show us the relevant code. So please edit your question to show us a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I mean as how can I get the current document's id?

Comment: Can you Update your question with code, so that we can able find proper solution

Comment: I have already found the answer, but thank you all anyways.

Comment: Can you post your answer here? so that it will be helpful for others who are facing same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to do this is:

`doc_ref = db.collection(u'ENTER THE COLLECTION NAME').document()`

`id = doc_ref.id`