# Get document ID from newly created document in firebase and flutter code

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I need to retrieve the document ID from a newly created Cloud Firestore document, but I am not sure how to do this.

I call a save function that in turn calls another function. Here is the code below:

```
ref.read(clientNotifierProvider.notifier).saveClient(ref.read(clientNotifierProvider));

saveClient(client, [clientId]) async {
      firestoreService.saveClient(newClient, clientId);
}

Future<void> saveNewClient(client) {
    return _db.collection('client').add(client);
}
```

How can I obtain the document ID and then pass it back to the original calling function?

Comment: see if this is what you need [how-do-you-get-the-document-id-after-adding-document-in-cloud-firestore-in-dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054460/how-do-you-get-the-document-id-after-adding-document-in-cloud-firestore-in-dart)

Answer (score 1):

When you call [CollectionReference#add()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/CollectionReference/add.html) method it:

> Returns a [DocumentReference](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference-class.html) with an auto-generated ID, after populating it with provided `data`.

This means that it writes the data to Firestore with an auto-generated ID. If you need to have this ID before writing the data to Firestore, then you have to call [DocumentReference#set()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/set.html) on a `DocumentReference` object. This also means that such a document contains an [id](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/id.html) property which contains:

> This document's given ID within the collection.

Once you have this ID, you can then pass it to the [CollectionReference#doc()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/CollectionReference/doc.html) function so you can write the data to Firestore.